# How to sort lsit of objects by name and surname alphabeticaly in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I'm trying to sort a list of objects (users) that contains name and surname alphabeticaly.
I tried creating a pipe like this :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'sortAlphabeticaly'
})
export class SortAlphabeticalyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any[]): any[] {
  return values.sort((a, b) => a['name']+a['surname']).localeCompare(b['name']+b['surname']));
 }

 }
```

what i want is to sort this list for example :

```
   {id: '147822', name: 'Jhon', surname: 'Thierry'},{id: '156455', name: 'Messi', surname: 
   'Lionel'}
```

then the list ,sorted by name and surname, will be shown in this format  :

```
    name surname 
    name surname
    name surname
```

as i said i tried that pipe but it deosn't work for me!
Do u have an ideas for that ?

Comment: Firstly, you've got your parentheses wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by the `surname` property first, then `name` to end up with results sorted by `name`. Any users which have the same `name` value will be sorted by `surname`.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgWwgBTgJ2AZygXigbwCgooA7RCALik2DQEtSBzAbmJoFc1ylraHmbAL5tCAMw6kAxsHoB7UjTkYAQiHhIoAHgAqUCAA9gEUgBNsGlOiwA+ABQ8ImajoDaAXQCULjwXZoIYC5FVwA6cMdMd3YSUMxlYDs7fExgimo4IQAaAlTudKgAIyFPXBsoOFCAGzkpOCqIAGE5BDB0CDtCz08YqDiEpPxHDOyCYaKSsorq2vqmlraAzu7hQkIpBVooDkwINGw8V3Z8elNqAHIARgBWADYAFmvr85zx84BZJ0x6F8583ig5wAMvJSBAqudssdThdLvcAOwADgATMjfm8AFIACwUvzybx0WPoezQIEhWUI7lEG1IW3iGAgplwSlU6godh2e0wnjYNPiDRmTDs9OMplCCDgYEGjhy+Iokxw5QABgASIbyqBquVIIRKlaEIA)

```ts
type NameParts = {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
};

function sortByName <T extends NameParts>(names: T[]): T[] {
  return [...names]
    .sort(({surname: a}, {surname: b}) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .sort(({name: a}, {name: b}) => a.localeCompare(b));
}

const users = [
  {id: '156455', name: 'Messi', surname: 'Lionel'},
  {id: '147822', name: 'Jhon', surname: 'Thierry'},
];

const sorted = sortByName(users);
console.log(sorted.map(({name, surname}) => `${name} ${surname}`)); // ["Jhon Thierry", "Messi Lionel"]
```